# How can I place a button bar under a table in a UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I was wondering- is there a way to do this? What I got looks like this right now:
[image]

How can I make the bar fixed at the bottom and not floating under the table?

Thanks

Comment: Are you forced to use a `UITableViewController` instead of a generic `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following these instructions and tell me if you still have the problem.

1. drag a viewController into the storyboard
2. drag a toolbar and put it at the bottom
3. drag a Table View and put in on top

final result should look like this

http://imgur.com/I7VD1Bi